# How would be translated this simple input python code into dart?

Tags: python, dart

I am using dartpad to try learning some dart code and i found some answer here in stackoverflow but when i try in dartpad it does not work, below i will provide some simple python code and it would be very helpful if someone would help a little bit just to understand how it works in dart, or refer any link to any article.

input in python:

```
input_string = input("Enter something here: ")
print("You entered {}".format(input_string))
```

here is dart code that i tried in dartpad:

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:async';

void main() {
    print("Please, enter a line \n");
    Stream cmdLine = stdin
    .transform(new StringDecoder())
    .transform(new LineTransformer());

  StreamSubscription cmdSubscription = cmdLine.listen(
    (line) => print('Entered line: $line '),
    onDone: () => print(' finished'),
    onError: (e) => /* Error on input. */);


}
```

Comment: You can use `stdin.readLineSync(encoding: utf8);` to read a line of text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like

```
print('Enter something here');
final line = stdin.readLineSync(encoding: utf8);
print('You entered: $line');
```